# How to put customized footer in tcpdf after using $pdf->PrintChapter() method?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I want to put a footer say www.abc.com at the end of every page of my PDF document. I'm using `$pdf->PrintChapter` method to print the data in two column format.

If I use the Footer() method override logic to print this customized footer, it gets printed at the end of PDF sheet(means only at the end of last page in PDF, not after every single page ). My requirement is to put the footer at the end of each page along with the page no. Page no. is getting printed automatically, I want only the text `www.abc.com` as a footer at every page end. I'm attaching the screenshot of one of my PDF document's page with this question for your reference. Thanks in Advance.[image]

Comment: This solution is given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067816/attach-footer-at-very-bottom-to-every-page-in-tcpdf

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with tcpdf since I use fPdf but the way I handle a footer on every page is to create a function that explicitly writes footer data to a specific x,y coordinate.  Then I bind that function to the addPage() method.  Thus, every time addPage() is called (a new page is created), it writes the footer data to the bottom of the current page.